# SSIS Import Excel to SQL Truncation Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, truncation

I'm using SSIS 2012 and SQL Server 2014. I've had this issue forever and have YET to see a viable solution - and I'm not sure why more people don't experience this issue. Here is my simple data flow task:

[image]

I receive numerous Excel files from clients. The problem is that some of the fields contain text that is greater than 255 characters - and as we all know Microsoft is NOT smart enough to read all rows (the first 8 records are read and assumes that if the first 8 rows are less than 255 characters then ALL the rows must be less than 255).

Of course this leads to truncation errors. Even if I set my SQL destination column value to `nvarchar(max)`, SSIS will still error out. As I'm sure many have experienced simply using SSMS and importing an Excel file manually will generate this error. For my SSIS package, I have a data conversion task that supposedly converts the source data to a format that can then be brought into SQL Server.  Apparently not.

Here is my simple data flow task with the offending column highlighted:

[image]

So, the limited solutions I've found online recommend sorting the data so that the widest text value is at the top so SQL Server can read it. I can't do this for hundreds of files each and every time. And I need the data in the original sort order, too, so that's not viable. Or I should insert a dummy record as the first row in the Excel file.

And how would this be done - in a script task? Again, over potentially hundreds of files? I've also heard I can change the registry somehow. Do I want to mess with that? Do any of these sound practical?

I have not seen anything online that's comparable to my situation - and I'm flummoxed. How can that be? I can't be the only one who experiences these types of truncation issues.

Anyway, I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I've started using EPPlus + Powershell because this problem (and related ones) have been around forever and they've never been fixed. The other problem I've had is that depending on that data in the particular file, the data length can change, meaning the data type reported by the excel driver changes at runtime (i.e. from character to memo), and then your SSIS package breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solutions:

1- Change the sample size by updating `TypeGuessRows` in the registry key for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel`. Path might not be exactly same in your machine but would be similar.

2- Use `Flat File Connection Manager` instead of `Excel Connection Manager`, right click, go to Advanced Editor, go to Input and Output Properties tab, find your column on the left under Output Columns and set its length to 1000.

[image]

Comment: a "flat file connection manager" - for an EXCEL file??!  How's that supposed to work?  I tried connecting to my Excel source file and the editor couldn't even recognize any columns.  Could you back up a step and show/advise how this works?  Thanks.

Comment: You can convert the excel into csv first, i believe.

Comment: Again, for potentially hundreds of files?  What if the data has embedded commas?  I appreciate the help but my experience with CSV files has been even more nightmarish.

Comment: CSV with an appropriate delimiter (tab, ~, |) is pretty reliable but the root problem is that excel is an unreliable data interchange format, and I agree it's usually not practical to reliably convert a bunch of excel to CSV. Although it can be done, you have simply have the same issue trying to recognise excel data types.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of my own frustration with SSMS's inadequate diagnosis of data types in imported data, I wrote a tool to do the job instead.  It works better for me; it might work better for you, if you're open to scripting solutions outside of the Microsoft environment.  The tool is a Python script, available at https://pypi.org/project/execsql/.  The [IMPORT](https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#import) command will read an entire Excel or CSV file to determine data types, pretty much guaranteeing that the data will be imported successfully.  Import from CSV is *much* faster than import from Excel, and line breaks inside columns of the CSV file are handled correctly.

Comment: Thank you.  i will explore this option.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what xlrd uses to read excel. Since .xls is proprietary, I assume in the end it's just using the JET driver anyway?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - It doesn't use JET.  The Excel file format was reverse-engineered years ago.  xlrd and other libraries can read Excel files on systems without JET installed.

Comment: Oh! That’s interesting to know!

Answer (score 0):

I used the formula =rept("x",4000) in first row of the Excel sheet, all columns (or all columns with a large size).  I then pasted values.  The column mapping then correctly interpreted the column as nvarchar(max).  After import, I deleted the first record.

Although I used 4000, it correctly imported cells that were much larger than 4000.  Somehow, 4000 was large enough for it to select "Max" as the field size.

(I then tested whether typing in the word "max" in the mapping for the field size would work. It accepts this, and creates output as nvarchar(max) but still truncates input to 255, so it is necessary to add this first record as described.  That works.)